# How to setup Cloud9 for io.js?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I've started to use Cloud9 to develop in node.js. However, [io.js](https://iojs.org/) seems to be the continuation of the node project.

I tried creating a new custom workspace, and then installing io.js like this:

```
wget https://iojs.org/dist/v1.4.3/iojs-v1.4.3-linux-x64.tar.xz

tar xf iojs-v1.4.3-linux-x64.tar.xz

cd iojs-v1.4.3-linux-x64

sudo cp bin/* /usr/bin
```

However, on the last step, it says:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/bin/iojs’: Read-only file system
```

So, I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong, or if there is any other way of using io.js with Cloud9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide uses curl and nvm and should work on Cloud9: http://allangagnon.nettryx.net/2015/01/31/installing-io-js-javascript-io-on-ubuntu/.